# Combining Similary function code into template

Tags: c++, templates

I have to write following type of code

```
if ( itr->second == "char" ) 
{
    MemberProperty<Owner,char> *ptr = (MemberProperty<Owner, char> *)GetterSetterItr->second;
    pw->writeChar(itr->first.c_str() ,(pOwner->*(ptr->m_Getter))());
} else if ( itr->second == "wchar" ) {
   MemberProperty<Owner,wchar_t> *ptr = (MemberProperty<Owner, wchar_t> *)GetterSetterItr->second;
   pw->writeWideChar(itr->first.c_str() ,(pOwner->*(ptr->m_Getter))());
}
```

There are going to be many types, is there any c++ trick, preferably template tricks, to reduce this to one single call for this type of code.

Comment: Your `write` functions are with different names, so the only thing, that comes to my mind is a dirty hack with `marco`s. I wouldn't use that.

Comment: I also though about macros. I was looking for avoiding those If loops, anyways ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming writeChar() and writeWideChar() are identical except for parameter types, you could restructure your code like this:

```
if (it->second == "char")
  pw->writeChar<char>(itr->first, GetterSetterItr->second);
else if (itr->second == "wchar")
  pw->writeChar<wchar_t>(itr->first, GetterSetterItr->second);
```

Then in the class of which *pw is an instance, replace writeChar and writeWideChar with a template member function:

```
template <typename CharType>
void writeChar(std::string str, /*the type of GetterSetterItr->second*/ arg) {
  MemberProperty<Owner, CharType> *ptr = (MemberProperty<Owner, CharType>*)arg;
  // the rest of code of old writeChar() and writeWideChar()
}
```